# Why does UIElement.MoveFocus() not move the focus to the next sibling element in a ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard-events

I have the following visual tree:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox Name="ElementWithFocus" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="200" KeyUp="handleListBoxKeyUp">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
</DockPanel>
```

`handleListBoxKeyUp` is the following:

```
private void handleListBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        ((UIElement)sender).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

When the `ListBox` has keyboard focus (really a `ListBoxItem` I'd guess), pressing `Enter` moves the focus to the first item in the `ListBox` instead of to the following `TextBox`. Why is this happening and how can I get the `Enter` key to act like `Tab` here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than calling `MoveFocus` on the sender, you should call it on the original source found in the event args.

The `sender` parameter will always be the `ListBox` itself, and calling `MoveFocus` on that with `FocusNavigationDirection.Next` will go to the next control in the tree, which is the first `ListBoxItem`.

The original source of the routed event will be the selected `ListBoxItem`, and the next control after that is the `TextBox` that you want to receive focus.

```
((UIElement)e.OriginalSource).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me why WPF thinks the next control after the `ListBoxItem` isn't just the next sibling `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: If you use FocusNavigationDirection.Down or FocusNavigationDirection.Up instead of Next the focus will move up/down on the ListBoxItems. Next seems to hit the next control that is not on same level as the origin.

Comment: @codekaizen Next/Previous is akin to Tab/Shift-Tab which in a ListBox are not used to navigate between items.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that gets the code to go to the next text box would be to raise the tab event manually.  Replacing your code inside the if statement with the following worked for me:

```
KeyEventArgs args = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Tab);
args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args);
```

Comment: I'd considered this, but I generally don't like replacing input since it can cause unintended side-effects with input filters like adaptive screen readers.